# WebDeploy to IIS - how to delete a folder on destination server?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, msdeploy, webdeploy

On the destination server I want do delete a folder (and all it's files) under the  App_Data folder.
It should happen just before I push the new files to the destination server.

How can I to this?

Current configuration

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>QA</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://qa.mysite.test:80/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://my-server:8172/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>qa.mysite.test</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WebDeploy to IIS - how to delete a folder on destination server?

You can check out the **Delete task** in MSBuild:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd15byf.aspx

You will probably have to create an `PropertyGroup` that will contain the folder of files to delete, then add the `delate` task into `AfterBuild` target:

```
    <PropertyGroup>  
      <AppDataFolder>AppdataFoler</AppDataFolder>  
    </PropertyGroup>
```

To accomplish this, unload your project, edit the project file .csproj. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag , place below scripts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>  
    <AppdataFolder>\\YourServer\Appdata</AppdataFolder>  
  </PropertyGroup> 


  <Target Name="AfterBuild">  
    <Delete Files="$(AppdataFolder)\YourDeleteFile" />  
  </Target> 

</Project>
```